# Java program to print a report

Tags: java, user-interface

I am currently trying to write a java program that has a nice UI that asks for three inputs from the user, Name, Project ID, Hours, and Date. I am using this to track my progress at work on all the projects I am currently working on. I have some java experience but I am still learning. So what I am trying to accomplish is create a program that takes the users input and prints a report to a text file. I have the fields set up and I have most of the interface set up how I want it. However I would like to have a button that prints what the user input to a text file. How do I do this? How do I go about taking the users input and printing to a text file? I would really appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1625263/16959 <- this is a single answer to the sub question, how to append to a file in Java.  As for "have a button that", how far have you gotten?

Comment: This question will be closed soon... is just too vague. For the UI read about java swing and for writing to a text file use FileOutputStream. Try to be more specific when asking in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

To print to a file, use the following:

```
PrintWriter fout = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("file_name.txt", true));
```

You can use `fout` just like System.out. Make sure to call `fout.close()` when you're done writing. The `true` in the constructor specifies that you want to append to the file; to overwrite the file, change it to `false` (thanks Jason).

Taking user input is a different question and the answer depends on how your interface is structured.